# To delete a queue from rqworker?

Tags: python

```
  from redis import Redis
  from rq import Queue


  a = Queue('remove_this_queue', connection=Redis())
```

I want to remove the queue "remove_this_queue". is it possible to do it in rqworker?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

**Using rq:**

RQ offers methods to make any queue empty:

```
>>> from redis import Redis
>>> from rq import Queue
>>> qfail = Queue("failed", connection=Redis())
>>> qfail.count
8
>>> qfail.empty()
8L
>>> qfail.count
0
```

**Using rq-dashboard:**

Install rq-dashboard:

```
$ pip install rq-dashboard
```

Start it:

```
$ rq-dashboard
RQ Dashboard, version 0.3.4
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:9181/
```

- Open in browser.
- Select the queue
- Click the red button "Empty"
- Done.